# How can I invoke a Callback action on the publisher of a PRISM CompositePresentationEvent?

Tags: wpf, prism, eventaggregator

Is it possible to invoke a callback action on the publisher of a PRISM CompositePresentationEvent after it has been handled by the subscriber? If yes, how can I do it?

Here is the example scenario:

- MainPage
- LeftControl
- RightControl

The LeftControl publishes an Event and RightControl subcribes to act upon the event. Upon completion of the action in the right control, I would like to execute another function to refresh the left control.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Hello Mark, we used regular .NET event in the LeftControl. This event is monitored by MainPage. Upon event firing, we called the RightControl's viewmodel method. We re-factored our design to achieve our need without eventaggregator. But the payload with callback did work in my sample. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Alright! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in possibility to do so. However, you could create a class for your payload, which contains a delegate. You can then execute the delegate from within the method, that subscribed to the CompositePresentationEvent.

```
public class Payload
{
    // Whatever you need here
    ...

    public delegate void CallbackHandler();
    public CallbackHandler Callback { get; private set; }

    public Payload(CallbackHandler callback)
    {
        Callback = callback;
    }
}
```

Create the payload in the publisher:

```
var p = new Payload(SomeVoidFunctionOnPublisher);
```

Then, when after you've handled the event in your subscriber, raise the callback:

```
public void HandleEvent(Payload p)
{
    // Do something first

    // Then callback
    p.Callback();
}
```

**Remark:**

The main idea behind CompositePresentationEvents is decoupling between components, which is kind of undermined by a callback, at least in a conceptual sense. Consider reworking your underlying architecture to avoid the need for a callback altogether. Alternatively think about, whether a second event, raised by the 'callbacking' subscriber could be justified.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Let me try this out.